# How to choose laser goggles for low-power laser of specific wavelength?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, laser, vision, laboratory-safety

I need to choose laser goggles to shield eyes against 678 (+/-8) nanometer laser (5mW power). The laser has a red beam.

I found for example some goggles that are sold for 650nm, with a blue lens. Must the lens color on the goggles be similar to the beam color in order to protect the eyes? How about the wavelength, can a lens that protects against 650nm be expected to also protect against 678 (+/-8) nm?

Comment: A link to the data sheet for the goggles you're considering would help answer the question. If there's no data sheet or it doesn't give an optical density value at wavelengths other than 650, you could ask the vendor for the o.d. at your wavelength.

Answer (score 4):

If the color of the lens is the same as the color of the laser, it's *not* going to protect you.

Your local regulations or university may set a specific standard, but a general rule of thumb is that for visible wavelengths like this, you would like the attenuated beam power to be less than 1 mW -- comparable to a handheld laser pointer.  At that power you don't want to stare into the beam, but an accidental glance [won't cause lasting damage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_safety).  The attenuation of laser safety glasses is measured in [optical densities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbance).  If you want to knock your beam down below 1 mW you need anything above 0.7 or so.  If you want to be able to see the beam with the glasses on, you don't want to make it too high.

Many places that sell laser goggles publish a chart which shows what the optical density is as a function of wavelength.  You should consult it to make sure before buying any, but chances are that goggles designed for 650 nm will probably also be ok at 678.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think it is important to start off by saying this:

For any question about laser safety always consult with your organization's laser safety officer!

To answer the question about choosing laser safety eyewear premised off the color of the lens - this is not the correct way to shop for laser safety products. Instead, looking for a pair of laser safety glasses that protect from the wavelength (or range of wavelengths in question) is best (as well as determining the optical density needed given your laser/situation - this can be the tricky part).

I thought this article on common laser safety industry notation for reading optical density would be helpful.

[image: Laser Safety Optical Density Notation Explained]

Often times, the laser may come with instructions as to what type of protection is needed to comply with laser safety standards.  It is always best to be safe and ask your lab's laser safety officer (LSO) to be certain.

Comment: Do you happen to be affiliated with the linked website? Note that when linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam.

Comment: Cigien, I posted this as I thought it was relevant to the question at hand (and relevant to anyone with a similar question).  Should I take the URL out of my answer?  IMO, this is the best image on the web for understanding Optical Density for laser safety. I posted this to aid individuals with like minded questions.  I had been researching this topic recently, and thought this image said it all (enough so that I actually thought it was useful in another StackExchange question in regards to optical density).  Please let me know if the URL is what caused you to write the above.  Thanks

Comment: It's not the URL itself that concerns me, only that you might be affiliated to that website. I notice that you posted multiple answers linking to that website, which also looks a bit concerning. If you're not affiliated in any way, and have only added the links because they improve the answer, that's perfectly fine.

Comment: Haha well, I sort of joined today (stackexchange) base on research that was relevant to all 3 posts.  Optical density/spectrophotometer and thought I would give back.  Is it normal to provide a source for an image like that or just take the link from the image?

Comment: Ah I see. No, you should definitely attribute the images you use, that's the right thing to do. Please don't remove the attribution from the answer.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the assistance :).  I'll be sure to site for each post I made.

Comment: BTW I understand if you're busy, but any feedback about the other posts I'd greatly appreciate it.  I've wanted to get involved with communities like this (as I end up using the information in my searches), and want to make sure I'm doing it right.  Like one question is:  If someone has a great answer and you simply want to add to it, when is it best to do an answer vs an edit?  When is an edit appropriate?

Comment: I'm not really qualified to give advice for this SE site *specifically*. Regarding edits, in general you should ask the author of the answer in a comment if they think the edits you would like to make are acceptable to them. If your edits are substantive, then you should write a new answer, as changing the intent of an existing answer is not a good idea. You should take a look at the [help pages](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help) if you haven't done so already, as a lot of these things will be covered there.